# If Cell equals Text then delete that row until end of range

Tags: excel, vba, rows

Need help as i Cant find anything online to achieve deleting all rows in a range starting from any cell in that range that contains the value "X".

```
Dim srchRng As Range

Set srchRng = Range("A10:A308")

Dim c As Range
For Each c In srchRng
    If c.Value = "X" Then
        
       ' Delete rows starting with row containing X until A308
                  
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `range(c, range("A308")).entirerow.delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim srchRng As Range

Set srchRng = Range("A10:A308")

Dim c As Range
For Each c In srchRng
    If c.Value = "X" Then
        
   range(c, range("A308")).entirerow.delete
                  
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this without looping.

```vb
Dim srchRng As Range
Dim Res As Variant

    Set srchRng = Range("A10:A308")

    Res = Application.Match("X", srchRng, 0)

    If Not IsError(Res) Then
        With srchRng
           .Offset(Res - 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - Res + 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End If
```